# Multiple Databases --Migrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am using 2 postgres databases in my django app.

```
 'newpostgre': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'new_postgre2',
    'USER': 'tester',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
},
'newpostgre2': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'new_postgre3',
    'USER': 'tester',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
},
```

I have a very simple model

```
 class Check1(models.Model):
         title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I had run

```
python manage.py migrate --database=newpostgre
python manage.py migrate --database=newpostgre2
```

when I open my new_postgre2(for newpostgre) database in postgre, I can see my Check1 table there.

But in my new_postgre3(for newpostgre2) database in postgre, no Check1 table is there, only those initial migrations are there.

Why I can't see my table in new_postgre3 when migrations have been successfully made?

Comment: Are you using any db routers ?

Answer (score 0):

Because The same object name can be used in different schemas sometimes conflict. The best practice allow many users to use one database without interfering with each other. Use this change second database user and check again. I think it is work.

```
'newpostgre': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'new_postgre2',
    'USER': 'tester',
    'PASSWORD': 'password',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
},
'newpostgre2': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'new_postgre3',
    'USER': 'tester_different',
    'PASSWORD': 'password_different',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '',
},
```

python manage.py migrate --database=newpostgre2

Comment: sorry bro, but that is also not working, thnks for your effort though. I have checked that database again,now with a different user, but again the default migrations are made but model is not present there.